# Redirecting audio output from one function to another function in python

Tags: python, audio

Suppose I have two functions drawn from two different APIs, function A and B.

By default, function A outputs audio data to a wav file.

By default, function B takes audio input from a wav file and process it.

Is it possible to stream the data from function A to B? If so, how do I do this? I work on lubuntu if that is relevant.

This is function A I'm thinking about from the PJSUA python API:

**create_recorder(self, filename)**
Create WAV file recorder.

Keyword arguments
filename    -- WAV file name

Return:
    WAV recorder ID

And this is function B from the Pocketsphinx Python API

**decode_raw(...)**

Decode raw audio from a file.
Parameters:
fh (file) - Filehandle to read audio from.
uttid (str) - Identifier to give to this utterance.
maxsamps (int) - Maximum number of samples to read. If not specified or -1, the rest of the file will be read.

update:

When I try to pass the filename of a socket or named pipe, it outputs this error message, seems that the C function that the python bindings use doesn't like anything but .wav files... Why would that be?

pjsua_aud.c .pjsua_recorder_create() error: unable to determine file format for /tmp/t_fifo. Exception: Object: LIb, operation=create(recorder), error=Option/operation is not supported (PJ_ENOTSUP)

I need to use a value returned by create_recorder(), it is an int that is used to get the wav recorder id (which is not passed on directly to decode_raw() but rather passed on to some other function.

Comment: It depends, what do you pass to function `A`?  Do you pass a filename, or a file object?  If function `A` can take a file object, you might be able to give it a StreamIO object instead.

Comment: It's a filename.... I'm going to edit my original post to give more info.

Comment: have you tried to pass a different name: `/tmp/t_fifo.wav` instead of `/tmp/t_fifo`?

Comment: Yes, I tried it yesterday and it worked. I took a look at the C code and apparently it just checks for the .wav extention... Thanks for the help, now I'm just looking for a way to get the return value from the create_recorder function

Comment: where is the returned value used? Do you need it before or after `decode_raw()` call?  If the former then the streaming will be problematic. Don't put info in the comments to your own question, [edit] it instead.

Comment: Actually, I need it before... Ok, I'll edit my questions from now on.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is highly platform dependent and more details are required. Different Operating Systems have different ways of handling Interprocess Communication, or IPC.

If you're using a UNIXlike environment, there are a rich set of IPC primitives to work with. Pipes, SYS V Message Queues, shared memory, sockets, etc. In your case I think it would make sense to use a pipe or a socket, depending on whether the A and B are running in the same process or not.

Update:

In your case, I would use python's `subprocess` and or `os` module and a pipe. The idea here is to create calling contexts to the two APIs in processes which share a parent process, which has also created a unidirectional named pipe and passed it to its children. Then, data written to the named pipe in `create_recorder` will immediately be available for read()ing in the named pipe.

Comment: I think they run in the same process... They're certainly in the same python script and I haven't touched anything fancy like multiprocessing (I don't know how anyway)

Comment: @MaxPie: The simplest thing to test—because it may work—is to create a Unix socket, and pass its filename to `create_recorder`, and see if it writes to the socket, replaces the socket with a regular file, or fails. If it writes to the socket, just pass the socket's file descriptor to `decode_raw` and you're done.

Comment: and this has the added property that since the socket is defined by a path and globally accessible, you no longer have to create it in a parent process which simplifies the implementation for a small cost.

Comment: Ok I tried the unix socket method but it doesn't seem to like it (create_recorder returns a funable to determine fileformat for /tmp/p_unix_socket, I followed the instruction here:http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.velvetcache.org/2010/06/14/python-unix-sockets, and I just passed the filename the socket was bound to createrecorder but it didn't work, I'm going to try what user931794 suggested

Comment: thinking about it some more, will that even work if the other two options didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a named pipe [`os.mkfifo()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkfifo) and move functions to different threads/processes e.g.:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process

os.mkfifo(filename)
try:
    Process(target=obj.create_recorder, args=[filename]).start()
    decode_raw(filename, ...)
finally:
    os.remove(filename)
```

Comment: That didn't work either, create_recorder complains that it doesn't recognize the filename/ not supported

Comment: @MaxPie: [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13884439/edit) to include the full traceback that you get.

Comment: It just says this in the console: pjsua_aud.c .pjsua_recorder_create() error: unable to determine file format for /tmp/t_fifo. Exception: Object: LIb, operation=create(recorder), error=Option/operation is not supported (PJ_ENOTSUP), how I get